# IIS 10 rewrite to internal port for both http and https

Tags: redirect, iis, https, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have a node js application running on the port `8080` in my Windows server and is accessible from inside of the server by `http://localhost:8080`. I want to use some subdomains like `app.mydomain.com` without using the port number from outside of the server to open this node.js application. I want to completely all traffics be rewrited to this port and there is no filters for subdirectories.

I've installed `ARRv3_0` and `urlrewrite2` on my IIS and also restarted the server too. Also installed a certificate on the server and assigned to this IIS website. Currently, I'm using this file as my `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to node server" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/{R:1}" />
                </rule>              
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also, I created an index.html file in the website directory too, but there is no difference.

[image]

I get 404 when I open the domain with both `http` and `https`.

[image]

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 mistake 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tips you need to pay attention to.

1. You need to check the Enable proxy in ARR. ARR->Server Proxy Settings-> Enable proxy.
   [image]
2. According to your proxy rules, when you proxy from one URL to another, only the domain is rewritten, so you have to make sure that there is page information in the URL, such as http://initialURL/index.html, and it will be the last Rewrite to http://localhost:8080/index.html. If you don't want to add index.html, you can enable default document and move index.html to first one.
   [image]

Comment: Hey, thanks. Number 1 has solved my issue. Just for anybody has this issue: you should install ARR from https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing first. then select your server name from IIS left sidebar, and open `Application Request Routing Cache`. As the above screenshot, just enable the first checkbox.